# I don't understand a part of the render to texture tutorial Apple providers

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I don't understand this particular part from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_offscreen/opengl_offscreen.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001987-CH403-SW10)

> 11 Render content to the texture. You must make sure to bind a different texture to the framebuffer object or disable texturing before you render content. If you render to a framebuffer object texture attachment with that same texture currently bound and enabled, the result is undefined.

First, I've just bound a texture to the framebuffer several steps before with `glFramebufferTexture2DEXT`, how do I unbound it now? And most important, why do I have to bound in the first place if I have to unbound it in the next instruction? Or should I bound another texture with `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);`. And what if I don't have another texture? Is it safe to use `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are talking about what needs to be done when switching between framebuffers *after* you have initialized everything.

But yes, you do use glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 ) to unbind a current texture. See this article for another example of binding and unbinding textures as you switch between frame buffers:

http://www.flashbang.se/archives/48

Comment: P.S. Ignore the part about MRT in that article, that's a feature of FBOs iOS doesn't support.